# Recover a phone number a dialed with no signal

Tags: data-recovery, network-signal

At the bar last night I got a number from an amazing girl that I dialed in the bar. I had no signal when I dialed the number (the bar was deep underground) and I don't see the number in my call history.

How can I recover this number?

Comment: you could check the notification history but i am afraid if it never reached entry in call logs it will not be in any log. this becomes the day where you truly hate android

Comment: next time send sms instead or save in contacts *amazing-girl* :)

Comment: Afraid you're out of luck here, see: [Android - Call log/ history : Retrieve a dialed number when there was no network coverage](/q/10922/16575).